# How to uncheck the radio button when checkboxes are checked and vice versa?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="a">
 <input type="checkbox" name="form">Apple<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="form">Banana
</div>

<div id="a">
  <input type="radio" name="form">A<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="form">B<br/>
</div>
```

when the checkboxes are checked the radio button should be unchecked and when radio buttons are cchecked the checkboxes which are checked should all be unchecked.

Comment: You shouldn't have two DIVs with the same ID.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks alot. How do i include the div id in jquery selectors?

Comment: `#xxx :radio` selects all the radio buttons within the element with `id="xxx"`.

Answer (score 1):

In `html` you cannot use `id` on more than one element. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_id.asp) you can read more about it.

Also names in input are better unique. For example - when you want to work with these data on backend.

```
<div id="checkingInputs">
 <div id="a">
  <input type="checkbox" name="inputFirst">Apple<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="inputSecond">Banana
 </div>
 <div id="b">
  <input type="radio" name="inputThird">Apple<br>
  <input type="radio" name="inputFourth">Banana
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is pure JS solution, since jQuery is already posted.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#checkingInputs input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 inputs[i].addEventListener("click", uncheckAll);
}

function uncheckAll() {
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i] !== this) { //make sure to not uncheck checked element
   inputs[i].checked = false;
  }
 }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3em2h01/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":radio").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(":radio").prop("checked", false);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dby2t/)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the answer? 113k rep; you should be good at this by now.

Comment: What's to elaborate on. The meaning of the code is self-evident.

Comment: This is easily considered a code-only answer. The only reason why it wasn't denied as such is because there's a link to a jsfiddle.

Comment: Further, you're feeding a help vampire. The question demonstrates a lack of *basic understanding* for the topic.